# how to remove duplicate toolbars?

Tags: interface

Please see the screenshot here:

[image]

At the top of the window I have 3 toolbars packed together, they are all the same.
How can I remove them?

Comment: Move the mouse to the small hatching until you see a cross cursor. Press the left mouse button and drag the cursor over to another area. It should become darker and display a small arrow. Release the mouse button and the areas will be joined. [For more details look here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames)

Comment: See this [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5633/12) for a visual demonstration as to how to go about this.