# How to recover the 3D view?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I pulled one of the lower sections of the blender to the top, and now I am completely unable to do anything.  I tried pulling the top down, but it's not the window I am looking for.

here is a picture of what it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Click and drag the handle in the upper right hand corner of the timeline down to split the view, then set the new timeline to a 3D view by clicking on the editor selection menu in the left side of the header:

[image]

See [How to close view windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5631/599) and [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames) for more information.

Comment: incredibly helpful, now i never have to ask this question again