# With upgrade to 2.78a menu bar for 3d View window is at the top

Tags: interface

In the 3d View window I am referring to the menu bar where you can select between vertex, edge, or face select. With my upgrade to 2.78a that menu bar is at the top of the 3d View window and I would like it back on the bottom of the 3d view window. How may I do that please?

Comment: btw, it's strange because the blender default has always been the same: at bottom. Since you're upgrading to 2.78a, while there's 2.78c and 2.79 makes me guess you're on some kind of linux distribution, and you're getting the upgrade from the OS repositories... if yes, the package maintainer should have changed the default file in this (and others?) way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on the menu bar and select Header>Flip to bottom.

[image]

Comment: Please read also through the following link to learn more about blender's interface: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51628/get-usual-right-side-toolbar-in-uv-editing-mode/51694#51694