# custom layout (via scripting)

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I am trying to transform blender interface my idea is to display only the 3d view, showing only the green area:

[image]

I want to remove the main toolbar, timeline, outliner and properties panels

So my first question is, is that possible ?

The second is, can someone point me in the right direction =)

Thanks in advance

Ghus

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close view windows?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows)

Comment: You could always just press `Shift + Space`.

Comment: I want to make this changes via scripting

Comment: I wrote about issues with joining areas here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?335823-custom-menu-for-views&p=2640545&viewfull=1#post2640545

Comment: Can you explain why scripting is needed for this?

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> (Cursor up) while the mouse pointer is in the viewport.

This wouldn't remove the main toolbar but is reversible by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> (Cursor Down).

You could get rid of the OS/Window-Manager decorations using Menu: Toggle Fullscreen <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>.

What you (probably) want is this:

[image]

Select 3D View Full and drag the main menu away.

From python you can select a manually prepared screen layout (save in the .blend) by:

```
bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['screen_name']
```

Comment: Note that this leaves the info editor open.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions but what I was really looking for was a script to make my changes more definitive and have a easy way to share this modifications.

Comment: @Ghus - *"I was really looking for was a script to make my changes more definitive"* ~ it would help if you explain more of why this answer isn't useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Would it accomplish your mission to follow the instructions at https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/interface/window_system/arranging_frames.html ?

Comment: hi bob 

thanks for the quick reply, i would prefer a scripting since i pretende to share this with other persons. Basically I am trying to make a simple 3d modelling program without all of this features.

Comment: @Ghus The layout is saved in the .blend file, so you could distribute it that way..

Comment: @gandalf3 do you know how to reach the startup.blend file? I can't find it in my hard drive

Comment: It should be in the [user or system directory](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout).