# Can not close windows in interface

Tags: interface

[image: Like 80 windows]

I have about 80 windows splits currently open, but I can't figure out why they wont close.
I tried Googling. I read the documentation, but the little corner grabbers don't seem to work.

Comment: @gandalf3 I read this article, the windows simply will not all join, surely there is a better way?

Comment: Make sure you drag them *out* of the window they are in to close. Another way to close view areas is by right clicking on the border between areas, and selecting *Join area*.

Comment: Note that you can't join areas that have areas in them, so you'll have to start on the smaller areas and work your way up. Though at this point you might  be better of reloading the .blend with *Load UI* disabled, just to get back to a clean starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to close view panels is well covered [elsewhere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows). However in your particular case I would recommend clearing out the UI layout completely and starting from a clean setup.

To do this, save and re-open your .blend with *Load UI* disabled. You can disable *Load UI* persistently, by deselecting the option in <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User Preferences > File*, or temporarily, by deselecting the option available while opening a .blend:

[image]

Also note that opening a .blend with *Load UI* disabled will keep the current layout, so to get back to the default you will have to load your startup .blend (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) first. Or if you want the *default* default, press *File > Load factory settings* before opening your .blend with *Load UI* disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can join windows very simply by right clicking on the edge between them
[image]
Click on join windows
[image]
Move the mouse to the side that you want merged

then click and it will have merged.
[image]