# How Do I reset my menu's on the right?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I swiped my menu's on the right all the way over to the left side of my window, and now I can't get it back, the menu window is blocking up the whole screen, and I can't get it back or remove the menu, or move it back to the right.[image]

The extremely annoying thing, is that I somehow managed to set this as my default interface setting, so everytime I open a new file in blender, or even start up blender, this is what I automaticly get...
I might be a noob mistake, or somtehing like that, but I can't use blender anymore!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21008/can-not-close-windows-in-interface and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts/855#855

Comment: Please add an image to your post so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Try resetting to factory default.
I always save a backup of the interface when I get it where I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the top left corner to change the window to 3D view (or whatever view you want)

[image]

You can also change the header to the bottom if you want.

To learn more about re-arranging the interface please read:
 https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/arranging_frames.html?highlight=windows