# All white render in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a big problem my render <kbd>F12</kbd> is all white, while my preview render is working.

Please help me guys, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendered image is just grey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/rendered-image-is-just-grey) also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: This duplicate was the solution for me: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/render-turns-out-plain-white

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render turns out plain white](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/render-turns-out-plain-white). I think Mark Kirby is right in this case. I don't see how the other answer proposed answer could be the solution.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. There are many reasons why this could be happening but the question does not have enough information for us to know for sure. Show an image of the UV/image editor that shows the full tool bar at the bottom. Also show an image of the nodes you are using to composite the scene. Is it possible that you have some object in front of the camera that is disabled in the preview but enabled for rendering? Do you have any strips on the VSE? please consider sharing your file to be inspected, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Note to all trying to get this closed as a duplicate, there isn't nearly enough information here to reliably mark it as a duplicate. It might look similar to another question, but as cegaton stated, there are many different reasons why this could happen. Any answers or duplicate candidates are purely speculation.

Answer (score 2):

If the answer isn't something to do with the post that Mark posted, it might be something to do with the planes you have in your object view, many are enabled in rendered mode, but disabled in view mode:

[image: disabled objects]

Alternatively, make sure you don't have a crazy bright lamp enabled in render but not in view.

Comment: That turned out to be my problem - thanks! It's not exactly intuitive relative to other software I used in the past (if it wasn't visible, it didn't render). ;)