# How to undo a window split?

Tags: interface

I know how to split a window (dragging the window splitter widget in the top right or bottom left of a window), **but how do I   undo it?**

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5631/599

Comment: There's no helpful Ctrl+Z for that, however, you can usually sort it out just by fiddling with the handles again a bit.

Comment: See [this video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/44837736) by Neil Hirsig.

Comment: there is join option next to the split option in the menu.

Comment: Again, I didn't read the manual thoroughly. Drag the splitter widget to the adjoining window, till the latter changes color. Then release. The windows are merged.