# Materials tab missing?

Tags: materials

I somehow managed to lose the materials tab in Blender. It now looks like this. It's my first time using it, so maybe I'm just being stupid. Also the other bars have somehow duplicated and I don't know how to fix it
[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows