# removed duplicated points, texture completely warped

Tags: texturing, uv

Newbie here again, I'm having some texturing errors... I made a little low poly dog for fun, and was finally able to texture something properly!

[image]

That is.. until I started to rig it. Everything was okay, except all the limbs were duplicated. So I went in, removed the doubles of all the points... and now the texture somehow became this monstrosity.

[image]

I moved the uv mapping around a lot while making this, and I don't want to have to redo it all again...

how can I get the texture to load properly on the model, like in the first picture?

Comment: The [scale isn't applied](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=apply%20transforms#apply-object-transformations) to the mesh, however this may be not the only problem. Is it right that you entered to Edit mode, selected all > `W` > *Remove Doubles*, switched toObject mode and noticed this changing in texture ? Also could you please [upload a .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for investigation of the problems (you can simplify it if needed).

Comment: hey @MrZak, [here's the file I was working with...](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/975/)
[here's the texture as well](http://i.imgur.com/IPFnhTW.png). I know it's a bit sloppy, but this is the first time I've been able to properly texture anything.. and even then I still screwed up :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible to repair by recognizing which island on UV map isn't needed for unwrap and deleting adjacent vertices. It's preferable of course to avoid such situations and check for double vertices / faces' normals / holes in mesh / internal faces / [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) etc. before starting unwrapping / rigging and so on.

The workflow consists in toggling between [*Keep UV and Edit mode mesh in sync*](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/texturing/layout_editing.html#selection-modes) modes in order to find selected vertices in UV map on the model.

1. Split the window and set the newly opened editor to UV/Image Editor. See [How to close windows](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows) for more info about closing / opening different editors inside Blender. In Edit mode select whole model with <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. In UV / Image Editor window select top islands of UV map because they don't preserve the unwrap, but do mess up the UV map and model when doubles are removed. In order to do that select them with <kbd>RMB</kbd>; to add to selection press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>. You should end up with top islands selected. Grab them and the bottom ones will be revealed (and hence the doubles are present):

   [image: Double islands on UV map]
3. Move those islands somewhere so that they don't intersect with bottom ones. Check *Keep UV and Edit mode mesh in sync* in the header of the UV / Image Editor. Use <kbd>B</kbd> to box select the top ones.

   You'll notice several vertices selected on the bottom ones, deselect them with Box Select tool (because these are shared vertices by both islands, thus if you delete them you'll loose the geometry of original mesh, not only double vertices). Hover mouse over 3D Viewport and delete selected vertices.

   [image: UV map repairation - last step]

   Now UV map shoudn't react on removing doubles because mostly they were already deleted, with preserving unwrapped islands.

   **[Blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/980/)**

Comment: One thing to note - in the file uploaded the scale for the model wasn't applied. Apply it with `Ctrl`+`A` > *Scale*. See [Why is it important to apply transformation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation) for more info

Comment: you're my hero, this makes so much more sense!! thank you so much, I'm so new to this and it's all so intimidating.. seriously, thank you!! <3

Answer (score 0):

The results obtained after removing doubles from the mesh are a result of having doubled vertices in your UV map, too. This seems to be most easily solved with a workflow change. After completing the mesh, apply scale and rotation, and remove doubles. Then do your texturing and rigging.

Comment: that's great and all, and I know that now... (I am extremely new to this)... but I'm trying to fix my current model, not all models in the future.

Comment: I can't speak to your situation, but I have usually found that sometimes it's faster to start again, than to try to fix the mistakes. And you might not have to start again from scratch; the seventh icon to the left of the search bar in the file browser header toggles "show .blend1, .blend2, etc. files". You may be able to find a file from just before you started rigging and unwrapping that would let you could use without going all the way back to the beginning.