# Removing doubles corrupts UV mapping

Tags: mesh, uv

When I remove doubles from my mesh the texture becomes corrupted:

[image: screenshot of removing doubles corrupting texture]

But the UVs are the same so I don't know.

Somebody know how can I fix it ?

Comment: Removing doubles is best before texturing because it can change mesh (especially if there were double islands in UV map), see if helps - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46406/removed-duplicated-points-texture-completely-warped

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked, the textures are the same. (I did the same thing like you) I uploaded my blend file : [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1261" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1261/)   (in this blend file the doubles of the mesh not removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation in your case is a bit similar to one in the linked post in the comments, except for the fact that here are 4 islands overlapping and they do that in a bit more difficult way (see below). In the next screenshot you can see what you can get from "one" island on the UV map if selecting and grabbing them out:

[image: screenshot of revealing islands]
<sub>Left - original UV map, right - all islands revealed</sub>

The problem however is that you can't just select those revealed islands, select adjacent faces in the mesh (*Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync*) and delete them. Some of overlapping islands are those which should be preserved (meaning if repairing this UV mapping).
So to delete only double faces you should find only those which do not affect UV mapping as you see it. In order to do that:

1. With all islands revealed check *Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync* in the header of UV / Image Editor.
2. Unselect all faces and use <kbd>B</kbd> (Border Select tool) to select one of revealed islands.
3. Move selection in UV / Image Editor and you'll see texture changing in 3D Viewport. The trick is to find those faces which *do not* move; those are the doubles and the ones which should be deleted.

   [image: finding which faces aren't important for UV mapping GIF]
4. Repeat that for other islands; once finished you'll get not very nice UV map and mesh with texture looking the same. The *Remove Doubles* operator won't affect UV map any more and you'll be able to delete remaining double vertices:

   [image: removing doubles doesn't corrupt UV map any more GIF]

The UV map will look like partially stolen, and I don't *think* you can automatically gather it back again. However quick and dirty solution will be to select former overlapping islands and move them back to main ones (not the best solution though).

[image]
*<sub>The checker texture isn't packed in blend</sub>*

Comment: I've got a new question about this: How can fix the dark parts ? (these are can be see in solid mode) http://www.kepfeltoltes.hu/view/160506/blend1_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian This is caused by custom split normals data, see [similar situation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47142/buggy-shading-on-a-simple-model) or  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/what-does-it-mean-when-my-angle-setting-under-auto-smooth-greyed-out. To handle mesh without those black areas most likely you'll need to delete it (though there are ways to handle with that data). If you have any questions about that ask them as new question. Btw file linked in question still has some doubles, here is one fixed - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41735

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for the fix, what did you do with the model to be smoothed like that ? I want to do it myself too for practice (I tried to remove doubles and clear custom split normals data but it was not the same result as yours).

Comment: In your case [clearing custom split normals and recalculating normals](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LsqoP.gif) will be enough to get rid of black areas. Keep in mind that all edges of model are marked as sharp, so Smooth shading won't make them being smooth; to change that select all, `Ctrl`+`E` > *Clear Sharp*. If you have any specific questions about these operators or other ones which weren't answered on this site please [ask a new question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

I found a the most easier way: I just need to select the surface faces in 3d view and delete them, then I can use remove doubles. If I had known this I could save hours before.