# The textures on my model are too dark

Tags: texturing, shadows

This may have been said already, or really simple to fix, but I've searched for 30 mins and found nothing

My issue is that every time I try to texture my model it turns nearly completely black.

Screenshot: [image: As You Can See The only ting providing light is the light (funny enough) so I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to fix it]

Comment: unrelated to your question, but to clean up the interface read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only light in your scene is behind the object, in other words the face and front of the object is in the shadow. Move your light so that it shines where you need it.
[image]

Other thing that might help you is adding some environmental lighting so that the shadows are not as dark.