# Limited options in a certain area?

Tags: texturing

Ok so i am a bit of a noob in blender, so I need help with this.

I am trying to texture something, but there is no texture button where there should be, because the blender edge window cuts it off
here's a picture

[image]

Comment: You have to hover over it, and then scroll up and down

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Hover your cursor over the buttons, press <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> and drag it left/right
2. Place the cursor on the window edge and expand the panel with <kbd>LMB</kbd>
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Mouse over the strip that is pictured and use your mouse's scroll wheel. You can also resize the *Properties panel* window. You can read more about resizing view windows in [How to close view windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows)

*Resize window shown first; then scrolling:*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Either resize the window if you have the available screen space for it, or use the middle mouse button over the header to scroll the tabs

[image: Resize or scroll header]