# Why can't I add a modifier to this object?

Tags: modifiers, text-object

[image]I am currently trying to make a standard youtube intro for a new channel depicting words doing different behaviours. The first word was flawless; however the second word wont cooperate and I can't add a modifier to the text. I am sort of following a youtube tutorial by tutor4u https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AV_ikY_Gss&t=230s. The modifier needs to be added after the text is converted to a mesh. I'm in cycles render as I should be. Any ideas?

Comment: you don't give enough informations, perhaps share your file

Comment: If you're using different font than the default Blender font, it might be that the mesh you get from it is not clean enough for the remesh modifier. But yeah, providing .blend would be helpful. Also, do you actually mean the remesh modifier is the one that's causing you trouble here?

Comment: Hi. Please explain your problem clearly, preferably with images, explaining what happens when you try to add a modifier to the text object, other than it "won't cooperate".

Comment: The "Factory" part of the intro was successfully created. Tthe "One Arm" part is giving trouble. Converting it to a mesh and then mesh from curve (Alt+C) is creating a problem. I need the modifier for the fire illusion. The font is default (same as Factory word) so there shouldnt be any issue there. Not sure where to attach a blend file (no attachment option in the edit portion.

Comment: You can include files via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for use here. However first make sure to scroll up the modifiers tab to the top since on your screenshot it's scrolled way down and it's not visible what is on the top there

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56215/limited-options-in-a-certain-area

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I was able to add a modifier by getting really mad at the program and restarting it a bunch of times! However i still need assistance if anyone is willing. The problem is: I created the intro with the fire (so the machinery writes "Factory" and the "One Arm" appears from fire) HOWEVER the words "One Arm" are not transulecent as they should be BEFORE being created by the fire. And the color is white instead of yellow. If anyone could help me resolve these issues that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: the blender file is 107 MBs as there is a lot of detail in the file and i want it to render in higher quality, so anyone willing if you could drop an email ill get it over to you! Thanks again