# Where did my properties interface/panel go?

Tags: interface, properties, panel

(Not the one you get when you key <kbd>N</kbd>), the one that has all the texture/world/material properties.

I was in edit mode trying to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> but messed up and now the panel is just gone. I don't know why or how to get it back. And it's not letting me *Split Area* or *Join Area* to make a new window, either.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you include screenshots? Does [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows) help at all?

Comment: Maybe you pressed `Shift + Spacebar` by accident?

Comment: Finally figured it out. In the almost top right. The main window but not the top menu going horizontal, use the pull tab to pull what seems like the menu brought up by N and pull it left to duploicate your entire screen. then you can use the "current view" button, the little cube icon in the very botom left of blender, but now can be found the in botom left of your duplicate screen on the right, and select properties. Done