# How can I go back to the original interface layout?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

[image]

I don't know what the hell I did I just want to get back to modelling

Comment: I think you are asking about reason of the suddenly appeared big window with green line inside. You grabbed splitter between these windows way up and now 3d Viewport is in the top. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save and close your file, fully close Blender and then open a new Blender instance with the correct default layout.

Then go to *File > Open* and browse to open your desired file, but **before you open** uncheck the *Load UI* option on the bottom left of the File Browser window.

If when you open Blender by default the layout is already messed up you may have to delete your `Startup.blend` file from the user preferences folder either under

- `Blender/2.##/config` for portable installations or under
- or `%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.##\config` for formal installation, generally under `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<VersionNumber>\config` for Windows users

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer if it helped you or mark it correct if it solved your problem