# My Blender display is cut in two

Tags: installation

[image: cut-up display screen]

No matter what my display settings are, the main Blender screen is split in two and the two halves are displayed back to back. In other words ][ instead of []. Help!

No, these are not two separate view windows. It is one view window cut in half.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close view windows?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows)

Comment: @Timaroberts Maybe, but it's strange that the right half would fit exactly on the left half of the screen. Maybe it's rather a display driver issue? user35648 Could you provide this Blend file? Just save it somewhere and upload that to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for investigation. If it is a UI split thing, that should be easy to replicate.

Comment: imho there's something strange here, there shouldn' t be that black gap, never... could it be a graphic driver issue with blender's opengl drawing? Does this happen with past blender versions, and with any file? which kind of device is this?

Comment: Have you tried the following: restart blender, restart computer, uninstall --> reinstall blender, install older/newer version of blender?

Comment: I am attempting to run Blender 2.77 on an ASUS A555DG (AMD) laptop running Windows 7 Pro. Installing another Blender version would probably be time-consuming and would not be my first choice. A sticker affixed to the laptop says "Radeon R8 M3500DX 2GB." Device Manager says there are 2 graphics drivers, "AMD R5 M330" and "AMD Radeon R7 Graphics." The version number for each of these drivers is 16.300.2311.0, 7/18/16. I'm a total Blender noob and have no idea what a Blend file is or how to obtain one.

Comment: Hold the presses: there's an AMD driver hotfix released 9/21/16. I will attempt.

Comment: Tried updating display drivers. Tried loading 2.78. Tried running as admin. At Blender startup I get a message, Failed to load 44100 Hz something something 48000 Hz (the message comes and goes too fast). Same problem.

Comment: That message `Failed to set 48000hz` [shows up a lot](https://developer.blender.org/T44416), I get that too I think, it has nothing to do with your problem.