# I cant get back to edit my model, how do i do this?

Tags: texture-painting

[image: i cant get out of this]

i am unable to get out of this to get back to my model

Comment: It depends on where you'd like to get out. E.g. there's UV editor opened on the most part of the screen in the screenshot. If you'd like to see the mesh you need to open 3d viewport editor. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows (but for opening)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get back to the 3D view click the bottom left icon to "3D view" as Paul suggested if you want to see the the image again change the "paint" drop down to "View"
[image]