# How do you open up the menu with the color preview and the modifiers?

Tags: modifiers

I was using blender and i accidentally closed the menu on the right and i cannot get it open. It appears there is no button or shortcut to open it from the search menu. Any help? Ive done so much and i dont want to restart it.

Comment: Press "N" to toggle that. Pressing "T" will toggle the one on the left.

Comment: that is a different menu, im talking about the one where you can add modifiers

Comment: You're searching for Outliner window. Other than that follow the steps from here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows

Comment: i don't need to close windows, i need to open the properties and outliner window.

Comment: nevermind, i just figured out how to fix it. Thanks though.