# Issues with getting to the material button

Tags: materials

I'm *very* new to blender, and I'm following a guide on how to make and color spheres, but I can not get to the materials button to get any farther. The farthest one in the properties tab I can get to is data, and I can not find a way to get any further right. How do I fix this issue so I can get to the materials? Also I have another question, I'm not sure what to call it, but the lower right portion of the screen with lots of options, when I drag from the right edge of the screen, it makes another portion with the same settings, so how can I get rid of these extra portions without having to restart? Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to bse.  Please ask only one question per post .  On part one, try scrolling mouse wheel while over properties icons, and [part two](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows)

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you for your response, This worked fine. If you put this as an answer I would be glad to accept it

Comment: another option is to enlarge the properties area, dragging its left corner to the left, so to leave more space and show all tabs...

Comment: You can hold MMB over any header and move it left and right if it's longer than the region.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should include some extra information like a screenshot for example. Are you using the "Blender Reder" or "Cycles Render" (I marked the setting in my screenshot where you can see that). If you could include a link to the guide that you are following it would also make things easier.

Follow these steps and you should be able to get to the material and make your object colorful. ( The numbers of the steps are marked in the screenshot so you can find the buttons easier. )

**Step 1.:** Make sure you are in the default screen layout. (This schould be already the case)

**Step 2.:** Make sure you selected the object you want to change the material of. If it is selected you should see a small orange line around it in the 3D-View. It also gets highlighted on the top right corner. If your object is not selected yet just right click on it in the 3D-View or left click on it in the top right corner.

**Step 3.:** Click on the material icon. If you can't see it just pull the properies panel more to the left so it becomes bigger. Now you should be able to change the material of your object. If you want to see the material on you object in 3D you might go to Step 4.

**Step 4.:** click on thet icon and select "Material" or "Rendered". (Note thet you might want to add a light source if you select "rendered".

[image]