# Getting window back that contains modifiers, etc

Tags: interface

I accidentally got rid of the menu/window at the right side of the screen which contains the modifiers button and the textures button (and a bunch of other stuff).  Now it's just the Outliner window over there.  How do I get the default one back?  I tried clicking on the little button that contains a bunch of different window types (Properties, 3D view, etc.) but none of them were the right one.

Comment: Properties editor type you listed was the right one. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows/5633

Comment: Oh, duh, thanks.  I didn't recognize it.