# I Want To Change The Blender Interface

Tags: interface

I have seen many people do it but I'm stuck with is this.

[image]

[image]

I want to know, how do I go from the regular default interface whenever you start a new blender project, to having two 3d views, and properties at the bottom? here's an example of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Move the mouse to a corner of an Area or window until the cursor changes into a plus shape. Then click, hold and drag. Then you can change the Editor Type by clicking on the Editor Type icon in the Header. Related:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows

Comment: You may also find this [Blender custom workspaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGt3iX5DHzg) YouTube tutorial helpful.

Comment: alright. i did that and i got the way to change the interface now. thanks for your help.

Comment: now, one more thing, how do i change the blender interface's color from gray to black in blender 2.79?